# css Absolute position and inherit display break ul li with a new line

Tags: html, css, css-position

I just stripped a portion of my very gigantic code where a weird thing happen:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .something {
            position: absolute;
            display: inherit;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a UL</p>


<ul>
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li title="Press Enter to validate">
        <div class="something">
            <span>Text 2</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css Absolute position and inherit display add a new empty line above the li. 
How to remove that line without removing the existing css ?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: The Div inherits the ul display, That ul has display list-item

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have a "**ghost**" `li` point, you should do this:

```css
.something {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a UL</p>

<ul>
    <li title="Press Enter to validate">
        <div class="something">
            <input type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Add a new topic">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The property `display: inline;` will fix that without removing any CSS, you only have to change this.

I don't know why this exactly happen, but the problem is that `div` tag creates a new line. By setting its `display` to `inline` it will fix the problem, because it will assure that `div` only **displays** in an unique line.